# Php sort by title in lumen

Tags: php, sorting, lumen

I'm doing some php in lumen and trying to sort movies by title.
I been trying to use sort but didn't get it to work..

```
class MoviesController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $posts = Movie::all();
        return $posts;
    }
}
```

The code is now printing out the list of all the movies.

Comment: SO is not supposed to be a replacement for a [quick look at the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#ordering)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$posts = Movie::all()->sortBy(function($movie) {
  return $movie->title; });
```